# formatter error when run program using rubymine tools

Tags: cucumber, rubymine

When i run some multiplication program in rubymine tool, below error appears. How to fix it
Error creating formatter: Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter (LoadError)
Please let know

Comment: Are you running Cucumber tests? Could you please specify Cucumber gem version?

Comment: Yes. cucumber version - 4.0.1. RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.4; INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0; GEM PATHS:
   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
   C:/Users/name/.gem/ruby/2.6.0. I ran simple muliplication program in rubymine 2020.1 version and ran into many problems. Rubymine tool log shows as follows:

Comment: That appears to be a known problem so could you please add your vote there and follow it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-26328